How to make VS Code formatter add spaces betwee angle brackets and only angle brackets
The formatter leaves no spaces between brackets, for example:
std::vector<std::vector<int>> example

So every time I use it the compiler returns an error thinking the >> part of the code is a left shift. How do i make it so that the formatter leaves the space between angle brackets untouched? Thanks.

An application called clang format can help.
